# Regex expression to english

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find out what my following regex expression will to to a string which could contain a number or a string when it is applied to it.

```
(^A59)(07)([0-9]*$)
```

Answer (score 4):

The string must be in this format:

1. beginning of the string `^`
2. A59 `(^A59)` and first capture group
3. 07 `(07)` and second capture group
4. zero or more digits `([0-9]*$)` and third capture group
5. end of the string `$`

Note that the `^` and `$` are put in capture groups, but they are zero-width assertions (they are anchors) so they don't "capture" characters. So putting them outside of the `()` wouldn't change anything.

So for example, good matches are: `A5907`, `A59070`, `A590701`, `A5907012`

Answer (score 0):

`(`  - begin first group
`^`  - which will start at the beginning of the line
`A59` - and must be followed by the text "A59"
`)`  - end of first group
`(`  - begin next group
`07` - which must consist of characters "07"
`)`  - end the second group
`(`  - begin the third group
`[0-9]` - which must consist of character 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
`*` - occuring zero or more times 
`$` - followed by end of line
`)` - end of third group

Answer (score 0):

The string matching your regex must conform to the following conditions:

1. A59 (^A59) at the beginning
2. Followed by 07
3. Followed by zero or more digits
4. Since there's a ^ and $ at start/end, there is a restrictive match... easier to predict.